# Accessing the application after installing npm package

Tags: webrtc, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I followed the 3 instructions mentioned on this page...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams-webrtc-dg/latest/devguide/kvswebrtc-sdk-js.html

1) Download the WebRTC SDK in JavaScript by running the following command:

git clone https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js.git

2) Run npm install to download dependencies.

3) Run npm run develop to run the webserver.

I get the following output:

https://gist.github.com/shantanuo/f0273674c3ef66e71c874594adcbed86

How do I now access the app or test page?

---

Update:

I am hosting the application on my personal site and this is not working:

http://shantanuoak.com:3001

Answer (score 0):

You can access the test page on http://localhost:3001

Thanks for checking out KVS WebRTC!